# How to import data from SQL Server to access via adodb connection

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, adodb

I am attempting to import a column (`product_id`) from a table `products` where the product was purchased (`year_bght`) in 2018 from SQL Server to MS Access (same table `[products]` and column `[product_id]`) via an adodb.connection. I'm inside the VBA editor in MS Access attempting to pull data from SQL Server.

My debugger shows the error is on the `cn.Execute` line but I can't seem to figure out what it is. I know the connection is working because prior to `cn.Execute` I had `cn.Print` with a message box and the `product_id` were printing just fine

```
Public Function ConnectionString() As String
    ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=*****; Database=*****; Integrated Security=****;"
End Function

Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim rs  As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cn  As ADODB.Connection

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    cn.Open (ConnectionString)

    rs.Open "SELECT DISTINCT(product_id) FROM products WHERE year_bght='2018'", cn

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        cn.Execute "INSERT INTO products(product_id) VALUES ('rs.Fields(0).Value');"
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

I'm expecting to import the columns that `rs.Open` has filtered into the `products` [`product_id`] column in MS Access, but I get an error:

> Invalid object name 'products'

Comment: Your rs.Fields(0).Value is in quotes so its trying to insert that as a value.  You need to change it to:  " + rs.Fields(0).Value + "...  though this is not good practice but should fix your issue.

Comment: I changed it but it still keeps saying invalid object name "products"

Comment: Then your insert statement is not correct.  Check the DB in your connection string and ensure the table exists called products and that the schema is correct.

Comment: So instead of cn.execute I tried currentdb.execute and then it managed to start importing but for some reason it loses a connection after a while. Not sure if it's because of too much data ?